# Pandas: create column based on first off occurrences in column B after signal in column A

Tags: python, pandas, numpy-ndarray

I have A column with signal on == 1  and B column with signal off == 1 ,the rest values are zero.

```
data = {'A': [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        'B': [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

I need to create a column C where:

- A == 1 and B == 0 or 1, C= 1
- C = 1 till to B == 1, than C = 0

Here what the result should be:

```
df['C'] = [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

I used

```
df.loc[df['A'] == 1, 'C'] = 1
```

to set at 1 the row where A == 1, but I can not find the way to get first non zero in B column, after the 1 signal on A, and replace the other with zeros till to next 1 in A.

Answer (score 2):

You can do `mask`, with `transform` `idxmax` , mask here is to set B to 0 when A equal to 1 , since no matter what value of B, the C will be 1.

```
df['C']=(df.index<df.B.mask(df.A.eq(1),0).groupby(df.A.cumsum()).transform('idxmax')).astype(int)
df
   A  B  C
0  1  1  1
1  0  0  1
2  0  1  0
3  0  1  0
4  0  0  0
5  1  0  1
6  0  1  0
```

Update

```
s=df.B.mask(df.A.eq(1),0)
s=(s==1)&(s.shift(-1)==0)

df['C']=(df.index<s.groupby(df.A.cumsum()).transform('idxmax')).astype(int)
df.loc[df.A==1,'C']=1
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I noticed that following the rest of the rows, (are more than 600) starting from a certain point the result does not follow the desired

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome to stackoverflow.

This is a case you usually wouldn't use pandas for as the value of `C` depends on previous rows. And pandas is more about using "split-apply-combine" on independent measurements

If it is not runtime-critical I would probably write a plain old loop for this:

```
In [4]: C = [] 
   ...: signal = 0 
   ...: for _, row in df.iterrows(): 
   ...:     if ((signal == 1) and (row.B == 1)): 
   ...:         signal = 0 
   ...:     elif(row.A == 1):  
   ...:         signal = 1 
   ...:     C.append(signal) 
   ...:                                                                         

In [5]: C                                                                       
Out[5]: [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]

In [6]: df['C'] = C                                                             

In [7]: df                                                                      
Out[7]: 
   A  B  C
0  1  1  1
1  0  0  1
2  0  1  0
3  0  1  0
4  0  0  0
5  1  0  1
6  0  1  0
```

This won't have a good performance, but imho it is worth it to cleanly express the intent of your code if it is still "fast enough".

Answer (score 0):

Solution based on *iterrows* (as proposed in one of other answers)
may be too slow.

Define the following function computing the output signal for a group
of input rows (starting on each case of *A == 1*):

```
def signal(grp):
    return pd.Series(np.equal(np.where(grp.A == 1, 0, grp.B)
        .cumsum(), 0).astype(int), index=grp.index)
```

Then group *df* and apply this function:

```
df['C'] = df.groupby(df.A.cumsum()).apply(signal)\
    .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

## Edit

Yet faster solution, without grouping, is:

```
sig = df.A.replace(0, np.nan)
sig.update(df.A.lt(df.B).astype(int).replace(0, np.nan) - 1)
df['C'] = sig.ffill().fillna(0, downcast='infer')
```

For a sample of 7000 rows (your data repeated 1000 times) the execution
time of this solution is 14 times shorter than the solution by *YOBEN_S*.

Comment: There is the possibility that A starts with 0, what should be the solution for both options?

Comment: I corrected my second solution to take into account this case.